# C# Tab Control Data Update

Tags: c#, arrays, database, data-structures, tabcontrol

I'm making a C# database without using SQL but using arraylists and datastructs. I am making a football database and would like to use a TabControl in order to store the match details e.g Minutes played, goals scored and penalties. These are all using NumericUpDown. I have a panel on top of the TabControl with all these in and i can add new tabs but the data carries over and i want to be able to add different data for each match. Is there anyway of doing this.

```
        private void MinutesPlayed_Num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1. create a new structure that can hold results for 5 matches
        FootballClub TabStruct = new FootballClub(5);
        // 2. copy the content of the current ArrayList data structure    // into the new structure
        TabStruct = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        // 3. update the data structure to what the GUI shows
        TabStruct.MinutesPlayed[tabControl1.SelectedIndex] = (int)MinutesPlayed_Num.Value;
        // 4. overwrite the old data with the changed one.
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = TabStruct;

    }

    private void GoalsScored_Num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1. create a new structure that can hold results for 5 matches
        FootballClub TabStruct = new FootballClub(5);
        // 2. copy the content of the current ArrayList data structure    // into the new structure
        TabStruct = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        // 3. update the data structure to what the GUI shows
        TabStruct.Goals[tabControl1.SelectedIndex] = (int)GoalsScored_Num.Value;
        // 4. overwrite the old data with the changed one.
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = TabStruct;
    }

    private void PenaltiesScored_Num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1. create a new structure that can hold results for 5 matches
        FootballClub TabStruct = new FootballClub(5);
        // 2. copy the content of the current ArrayList data structure    // into the new structure
        TabStruct = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        // 3. update the data structure to what the GUI shows
        TabStruct.Penalties[tabControl1.SelectedIndex] = (int)PenaltiesScored_Num.Value;
        // 4. overwrite the old data with the changed one.
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = TabStruct;
    }
```

Thats the code i have so far for when you change the data in that field.

Then this is the code i have for when i want to show which player we are showing.

```
private void ShowCurrentMember()
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData;
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];

        FirstNameTextBox.Text = PlayerMemberData.Firstname;
        SurnameTextBox.Text = PlayerMemberData.Surname;
        PlayerAge.Value = PlayerMemberData.age;
        Address1_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Address1;
        Address2_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Address2;
        City_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.City;
        Country_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Country;
        Postcode_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Postcode;
        HomeNumber_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.HomeNum;
        MobileNum_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.MobNum;
        Email_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Email;
        EmergName_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.EmergencyName;
        EmergNum_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.EmergencyNum;
        //if (PlayerMemberData.CardGiven == 'Y') YellowCard_RadioButt.Checked = true;
        //else RedCard_RadioButt.Checked = true;
        TotalTime_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.MinutesPlayed;
        TotalGoals_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.Goals;
        TotalPenalties_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.Penalties;
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ((FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown]).ImgFilePathName;

        FootballClub TabStruct;
        TabStruct = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];

        MinutesPlayed_Num.Value = ((FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown]).MinutesPlayed[tabControl1.SelectedIndex];
        GoalsScored_Num.Value = ((FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown]).Goals[tabControl1.SelectedIndex];
        PenaltiesScored_Num.Value = ((FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown]).Penalties[tabControl1.SelectedIndex];

        Player1.Text = "Player  " + (CurrentPlayerShown + 1);
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
```

Comment: Wait, so what happens when you close out of your program? All that data will be lost? Or are you planning on storing everything somewhere eventually?

Comment: I save the code to a text file which then opens up when i load the program.